# Columns total for categorical data

Tags: calculated-columns

How do obtain the totals for each of the column (in total 100) in the data frame. My data is a qualitative type.

For example

```
ID1   ID2   ID3   ID4   ID5     ID100

Y     N 
Y     Y
N     N
N     Y
```

And I want to find the total of columns (how many Ys and Ns) in ID1, ID2 and etc....

i have tried typing the following code

```
colSums(mydata[,[1:ncol(mydata)]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What language are you using? I think that might be R, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you had information about which package you're using for the array I could be more specific. Here's a general solution that assumes your array is a 'list of lists' where each column is a list item within a larger list.

```
def sum_array(array):
    """ Returns the number of Y, N for each column """
    for column in array:
        y_count = 0
        n_count = 0
        for cell in column:
            if cell == "Y":
                y_count += 1
            elif cell == "N":
                n_count += 1
            else:
                raise TypeError("bad entry")
        # print out count for each column
        print "column ", column, " has Y: ", y_count, " and N: ", n_count, " entries."
```

If you can provide more information, I'll try to help you with a more specific solution.